# Will these implementations cause memory leakage?

Tags: c++

Will the following cases cause memory leakage?
If yes, how can I solve the problem? Should I use a pointer in the `Base` class (i.e. `Structure* var`) and delete it in the destructor?

If case 2 does not cause a memory leak, what happens to `Structure(0,0)`?
It is instantly created and be destroyed or does something else happen?

**Case 1 :**

```
struct Structure
{
    int a;
    int b;
    Structure() { a=1; b=2; }
    Structure(int num1, int num2) : a(num1), b(num2){}
};

class Base
{
    private:
        Structure var;
    public: 
        Base(Structure structure)
        {
            var = structure;
        }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
    public:
        Derived(bool boolean) : Base(boolean ? *(new Structure(0,0)) : *(new Structure(10,10))){}
};

int main()
{
    Derived derived(true);
}
```

**Case 2 :**

```
struct Structure
{
    int a;
    int b;
    Structure() { a=1; b=2; }
    Structure(int num1, int num2) : a(num1), b(num2){}
};

class Base
{
    private:
        Structure var;
    public: 
        Base(Structure structure)
        {
            var = structure;
        }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
    public:
        Derived(bool boolean) : Base(boolean ? Structure(0,0) : Structure(10,10)){}
};

int main()
{
    Derived derived(true);
}
```

Comment: Not quite sure what you meant on the last part.

Comment: If you need more detail, add it. Don't spam and do some simple research beforehand. Try using valgrind's memory check tool or GDB to find leaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 1st alternative will cause a memory leak whether you pass `true` or `false` to the constructor of `Derived`. Exactly one `Structure` will be allocated on the heap, which is then copied by the default copy constructor of `Structure` when the assignment

```
 var = structure;
```

is executed.

If you:

- replace the internal `var` variable type by a pointer as suggested in the question
- `delete` the pointer in the destructor
- implement a copy constructor for `Base` taking care of duplicating `var` by a `new` allocation

you should not have any problem.

```
struct Structure {
    int a;
    int b;
    Structure() { a=1; b=2; }
    Structure(int num1, int num2) : a(num1), b(num2){}
};

class Base {
    private:
        Structure *var;
    public: 
    Base(Structure *structure) {
        var = structure;
    }
    Base(const Base &b) {
        var = new Structure(*b.var);
    }
    virtual ~Base(){
        delete var;
        var = 0;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 5):

Case 1 leaks because you have `new` with no corresponding `delete`.

Case 2 doesn't leak because you have no `new`.

Comment: If case 2 does not cause memory leakage, where do Structure(0,0) gone? It is instantly created and be destroyed immediately or something else?

Comment: You can only have memory leakage if you are using dynamic memory allocation (i.e. `new`). In case 2 you aren't using `new`, so everything is created on the stack and reclaimed when it goes out of scope.

Answer (score 2):

The first case is pretty bad:

```
  Derived(bool boolean) : Base(boolean ? *(new Structure(0,0)) : *(new Structure(10,10))){}
                                           ^^^^                    ^^^
```

You are dynamically allocating a `Structure` but you do not keep the pointer and so you have no way of calling `delete` on them and so you will leak memory. The second case does not have this problem.